# Matlab- Subtraction of previous in array plus addition of difference

Tags: matlab, difference, subtraction

So if I have a matrix s;

```
s = [4;5;9;12;3]
```

and I want to calculate the difference between an entry and it's previous entry plus add the previous difference such that I'll get

```
s = [ 4 0; 5 1; 9 5; 12 8; 3 -1]
```

I'm quite new to matlab. I understand a for loop would be required to go through the original matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second column of your result seems to be essentially `cumsum(diff(s))`. However, that's not "the difference between an entry and its previous entry plus the previous difference"; it's the *cumulative sum of differences*.

So, if what you want in the second column is the cumulative sum of differences:

```
result = [s [0; cumsum(diff(s))]];
```

Comment: That seems to work swimmingly well. Can't believe I didn't think of that. Cheers guys

Comment: When I use this for a bigger dataset I'm getting values of NaN. Any idea why?

Comment: @MRaff16 Are you sure your data doesn't contain `NaN`'s to begin with? Check with `any(isnan(s(:)))`

Comment: Just realised that. Will take the average of the previous and next value and try again

Answer (score 1):

In matlab you have a lot of functions for working directly with matrix, the one that feeds here is [diff](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.htmlhttp://) and [cumsum](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) please visit the matlab documentation, and the functions for concatening like horzcat or vertcat int his case manually to get what you need work like this:

```
>> s = [4;5;9;12;3]

s =

     4
     5
     9
    12
     3
```

Get the vector my_cum_diff which is the difference between elements in a vector

```
my_cum_diff = [0; cumsum(diff(s))]

my_cum_diff = [0; cumsum(diff(s))]

my_cum_diff =

     0
     1
     5
     8
    -1
```

finally concat the two vectors

```
final_s=[s my_cum_diff]

final_s =

     4     0
     5     1
     9     5
    12     8
     3    -1
```